How to pass value to rendered children?
I have an await block in my +layout.svelte for a product fetch function in the load function.
When the promise is fullfilled it renders a +page.svelte as a children and I need to pass the product to that page.
{#await $page.data.productData}
    <div class="flex flex-col flex-grow h-64 justify-center items-center">
        <Spinner />
    </div>
{:then product}
    {#key data.pathname}
        <div in:fade|global={{ duration: 300 }}>
            {@render children?.(product)}
        </div>
    {/key}
{/await}

in the +page.svelte that is rendered, how can I access product?
At the moment I'm using a context but I want to await only one time for the function.
onMount(async () => {
    product.set(await $page.data.productData)
});


I don't know if this is the best solution, but one solution is that you:

Create your own context in the layout component that stores null
You await the context (in the JS part of the layout), and then you store the resolved object in that context
In the HTML-part of the layout, you render the children when the context is not null
In the page components you can obtained the resolved object directly through your own context


+layout.server.js
export function load(){
    return {
        productPromise: getProductPromise(),
    }
}

+layout.svelte
<script>
    
    import { onMount, getContext, setContext } from `svelte`
    
    let {
        productPromise,
        children,
    } = $props()
    
    setContext(`product`, null)
    
    onMount(async () => {
        setContext(`product`, await productPromise)
    })
    
</script>

{#if getContext(`product`)}
    {@render children()}
{:else}
    <p>Still loading...</p>
{/if}

/sub-route/+page.svelte
<script>
    
    import { getContext } from `svelte`
    
    let product = $derived(getContext(`product`))
    
</script>

<p>{JSON.stringify(product)}</p>


But... That does seem like a quite complicated solution IMO ^^' It's not possible for you to await the promise already on the server-side? In its load() function?

I'm not sure I understand, can you make a code example? The function is in the load function, but it's a streamed promise, so I need to update the value after it's ready.

@Filippo, I added some code showing what I meant, but I'm new to Svelte 5, so not sure I got all the details right ^^'
